# Automatic trans/power steering fluid

Tags: transmission-fluid

We just got a 2006 Nissan Sentra and there is no owner's manual in the car. Can somebody tell me what transmission fluid to get for this vehicle? AND, does the power steering use the same fluid? I know many cars use the same fluid for both, but there are exceptions...   Thanks!

Comment: Start with a bit of research: https://www.nissanusa.com/pdf/techpubs/sentra/2006/2006-Nissan-Sentra.pdf

Comment: Which engine? Which transmission?
PS fluid is Genuine Nissan PSF or equivalent